# Why is my File Path Null using FileUpload in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

Why is my file path nothing when I browse for a file using FileUpload?
I don't want to upload a file, I just want to get the directory of a file (I'm using that file to update a SQL database with (xlsx file))

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" Height="24px" Style="position: static" Width="255px" />
<asp:Button ID="Uploadbtn" runat="server" OnClick="Uploadbtn_Click" Style="position: static" Text="Upload" Width="82px" />
```

Code Behind (Test is "") on Uploadbtn_Click event

```
string test = FileUpload.FileName;
```

Comment: Are you using updatepanel on that page?

Comment: You can't. For security purposes, the browser will never post the full file's path. The path is only relative to the client computer and once the file is uploaded to the server it is no longer relevant. The work around is to store the full path in somewhere else and then retrieve it on the server. You can use a hidden Textbox to store it, and use TextBox.Text on the server to get it. if you like too.

Comment: @MMK But is there another way to get the browser screen other than the FileUpload way I'm using?

Comment: @CarlosLanderas No I'm not, but I added it since you mentioned it just now, but still not giving my anything

Comment: @CarlosLanderas Thank you for your comment. Also saw that it doesn't work inside a Updatepanel. Thank you.

Comment: It work @Ruan, but you have to use a Trigger and assign the control id

Comment: You can check this: http://marss.co.ua/FileUploadAndUpdatePanel.aspx

Comment: @CarlosLanderas O.o Wow, okay. Thank you. (The amount of things I know is Staggering in comparison with the people on this community)

Comment: One day, I had the same problem you faced today ;). That's how we all learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read at MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filename.aspx), the filename will NEVER contain the directory of that file.

The software on the server is never allowed to take a peek inside the clients computer.

Comment: Oh okay, I get. So the client will have to physically upload the file, then I'll be able to use the file to update the database? The server can't just grab the file form the client even if they send through the file path?

Comment: That is totally correct! Of course, within a local netwerk, there are ways and you can modify your own securty inside your network, but this is not how an website should work.

Answer (score 0):

For this question answer is we don’t have chance to get full path of uploaded file from fileupload control because of some security reasons browsers will return only file name instead of full file path from client machine.
If you want to get full path of uploaded file from fileupload control from client machine we need to save that file in our application folder from that we can get path of that file like as shown below

**Code:**

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
fileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Files/"+filename));
string filepath = "Files/"+filename;
```

Hope you understand..